# Need to parse through XML to display URL in WebView. Best approach?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file that is downloaded form my server to the device storage.

I need to parse through this XML, storing several file paths/URLs and then loop through the resulting list/array/object to load the URLs in a WebView.

I am very new to Android Development and all the examples I am finding for parsing XML are not working for me (copy and pasting the code ends with lots of errors)

I think I should be using XMLPullParser to parse the XML file, but I do not know how to do this properly, using the local XML file, and saving the values to an array/list/object.

This brings me to the main part of my question - what should I be using to hold the parsed data? A normal array?, An object? A list? ArrayList? I'm really confused on this one!

Once I've got the XML parsed, I think I can figure out how to loop through it (depending on what the recommended way to store the data is)

Hope you can help!

Answer (score 0):

I think a valid beginner approach is to follow the official guide's tutorial on XML parsing. Click [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html), read the tutorial, download the sample code and modify it according to your XML file. It gets data from an XML, then it creates an HTML code from it and displays it in a webView.